# Jolt transformation: how to shift values to each map from list with hard coded attribute called partner on each key

Tags: arrays, json, transformation, jolt

I have been working on jolt transformation unable to find solution.

I would like to have attributeType and attributeValue to each attributeList and modelId unique with partner attribute value has hardcode

**Input**

```json
[
  {
    "MODELNUMBER": "A",
    "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "Capability",
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "0001",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "hd",
    "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "false",
    "RNK": 1,
    "batchNumber": 1
  },
  {
    "MODELNUMBER": "A",
    "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "Capacity",
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "0002",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "capa",
    "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "100",
    "RNK": 2,
    "batchNumber": 1
  },
  {
    "MODELNUMBER": "B",
    "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "Capability",
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "cat-0002",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "capable",
    "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "true",
    "RNK": 1,
    "batchNumber": 1
  }
]
```

**Expected output**

```json
[
  {
    "inventoryModelId": "A",
    "partner": "lava",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attributeType": "Capability",
        "attributeId": "0001",
        "attributeName": "hd",
        "attributeValue": "false",
        "rnk": 1,
        "batchNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "attributeType": "Capacity",
        "attributeId": "0002",
        "attributeName": "capa",
        "attributeValue": "100",
        "rnk": 2,
        "batchNumber": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "inventoryModelId": "B",
    "partner": "lava",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attributeType": "Capability",
        "attributeId": "cat-0002",
        "attributeName": "capable",
        "attributeValue": "true",
        "rnk": 1,
        "batchNumber": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a jolt transformation of the question.

Explanation :

1. In the first operation group the data by `MODELNUMBER`.
2. In the second operation transform input data to the desired structure.
3. In the Third operation convert the array of `inventoryModelId` field to single value and also insert the default value of the partner field

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "@(1,MODELNUMBER).[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "MODELNUMBER": "[#3].inventoryModelId.[]",
          "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "[#3].attributes[#2].attributeType",
          "ATTRIBUTEID": "[#3].attributes[#2].attributeId",
          "ATTRIBUTENAME": "[#3].attributes[#2].attributName",
          "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "[#3].attributes[#2].attributValue",
          "RNK": "[#3].attributes[#2].rnk",
          "batchNumber": "[#3].attributes[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "partner": "lava",
        "inventoryModelId": "=firstElement(@(1,inventoryModelId))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```